# Vuejs как сделать кнопку Выбрать все в checkbox?

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

Всем Здравствуйте. Возник такой вопрос. Есть массив checkboх, при клике на который он выбирается и я могу выбрать сразу несколько значений со страницы. Это все работает, хотелось бы добавить кнопку Выбрать все, чтобы не нажимать на каждый checkbox
Код

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data: {
            checkedNames: [],
          }
```

});

```
 <input type="checkbox" :value="item.id" id="usr" v-model="checkedNames">
```

Answer (score 0):

Поиграться [sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const input = ['Jack','John','Mike']
const names = ref([])
const click = (bool) => names.value = bool ? [...input] : []
</script>

<template>
  <div>Checked names: {{names}}</div>
  <template v-for="(_, i) in input">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="input[i]" :id="input[i]" v-model="names">
    <label :for="input[i]">{{input[i]}}</label>
  </template>
    <br>
  <button @click="click(true)">Выбрать все</button>
  <button @click="click(false)">Ничего не выбрать</button>
</template>
```